# Extracting a Zip file with Japanese characters in the archive’s filenames?

Tags: windows-7, zip, 7-zip, japanese

I'm trying to extract files from a zip file on Windows 7. The filenames are in Japanese, but they just look like éñé▀é─é±é─ü[é╓é┐éσèGòùé▄é╟é⌐üÖâ}âMâJâZâbâg20110423. They include a 3D model file and it's resources, so if I don't extract it with the right names, the model won't load right. I've worked around this before by setting Windows to use Japanese by default for non-Unicode applications, but that does funny things to other programs. I've also tried running 7zip using AppLocale but that doesn't seem to do anything. Is there some way I can do this without setting Windows back to Japanese?

Update: I just tried it with WinZip, and had the same problem. So WinZip, 7zip, and Windows Explorer do not work.

Update 2: Here's the filenames before switching the locale to Japanese:

```
01.é▄é╟é⌐.pmd
01.é▄é╟é⌐ò╧Égîπ.pmd
02.é│éΓé⌐ò╧Égîπ.pmd
02é│éΓé⌐.pmd
03.â}â~.pmd
03.â}â~ò╧Égîπ.pmd
04.âüâKé┘é▐éτò╧Égîπ.pmd
04.é┘é▐éτ.pmd
04.é┘é▐éτò╧Égîπ.pmd
05.ê╟Äq.pmd
05.ê╟Äqò╧Égîπ.pmd
06.charlotte.pmd
06.æσcharlotte.pmd
map1.bmp
metal.sph
README.txt
shirome.tga
tateme08.tga
water.bmp
â^âÅâVPé╠README`
```

And after:

```
01.まどか.pmd
01.まどか変身後.pmd
02.さやか変身後.pmd
02さやか.pmd
03.マミ.pmd
03.マミ変身後.pmd
04.ほむら.pmd
04.ほむら変身後.pmd
04.メガほむら変身後.pmd
05.杏子.pmd
05.杏子変身後.pmd
06.charlotte.pmd
06.大charlotte.pmd
map1.bmp
metal.sph
README.txt
shirome.tga
tateme08.tga
water.bmp
タワシPのREADME
```

The folder name changed from that first garbled line I mentioned to うめてんてーへちょ絵風まどか☆マギカセット20110423.

Comment: Do they look like that after extracting or in the preview?

Comment: It happens before and after extracting, and that's the problem: the glitched filenames != the original filenames, so when I open the 3D model, it can't find it's resources.

Comment: Have you tried other archivers to see if they are better in terms of guessing the encoding, such as WinRAR, WinZIP and so on?

Comment: At the moment I've only tried Windows Explorer and 7zip.

Comment: @Karan I tried using Winrar to extract audio files from a rar file but the metadata was garbled. I tried using English version of Winrar first and then I also tried the Japanese version followed by the Chinese version but none of them extracted the files with the proper characters. I think the only solution is to change your system locale.

Answer (score 14):

A bit late on this one but in WinRar the command is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and then select the desired language.

Everything will be in English except the garbage characters will be in their proper language (assuming you selected the right one).

Comment: Are you trying for a [`necromancer`](https://superuser.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badge? 8-P

Comment: It would be quite deserved, as this was the only solution I found after like 30 minutes of googling for how to fix this cursed issue!

Answer (score 6):

It's a known issue, with a HotFix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2704299

Previously others solved it this way:
http://mikudance.info/help/AppLocale.html

Comment: I've got this issue on windows 10. Is there perhaps a hotfix for win 10? This fix only covers windows 7 and server 2008

Answer (score 5):

This is the most correct solution.
Download 7zip and execute the following command in console:

```
7z x -mcp=932 archive.zip
```

-mcp key will directly instruct archiver to use 932 (Japanese codepage) while unpacking zip.

Most other answers in this topic are non-applicable (e.g. Ctrl+E in WinRAR doesn't exist on some systems, perhaps depends on locale), other methods like converting text just will cause text corruption.

Comment: YOu could improve your answer by explaining it a little bit.

Comment: @RohitGupta done.

Comment: And I  have upvoted it

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried converting the filenames?

I found these tools:

- http://www.gofunnow.com/convertutf8/convertutf8.php?destencoding=43&srcencoding=27
- http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php.

  I got a garbled output when I converted CP932 to UTF-16:

  鴦�▀�─魍�─�[�╓�┐�σ鍜�▄�╟�⌐�ﾖ竈祟祀禹稈稟20110423

  Hopefully you'll get a better result.
- Use [iconv](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/linux/iconv.htm), which is included in OS X and Linux and can be downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gettext/) for Windows. Use it like this:

  ```
  iconv -f cp932 -t utf-16 file.txt > newfile.txt
  ```

  where file.txt is encoded in cp932 and newfile.txt is encoded in UTF-16

Comment: My output was garbled too.

Comment: Too bad it didn't work. Could you edit your question and add a few examples of filenames as you see them after uncompressing and what they  look like  using the trick of using Japanese for non-Unicode applications ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do manage to extract them correctly, if you later set the computer back to English, they might not work if the software using them cannot find the files! I would set the computer to Japanese, extract them, load the model in the relevant program and try renaming them in latin characters. I know it's a bit time consuming, but then they should work without any conversion.

Comment: Once I get the files extracted properly, I think it's OK--extracting them seems to be the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if an easier fix has been found, but I did find a way myself that worked, for me at least

What I did is download and install Locale Emulator, and open the zip using the Locale Emulator, then you can just extract it anywhere and the file names **should** be normal